# How to find if user not logged in for 45 days

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created table called Login in sql server where I have the columns `usercode`, `email` and `login_date` (login_date is `datetime` type)

So, i created web application using .net. whenever user logged in, I am allowing based userLoged table and I am inserting into login table.

Login table:

```
usercode  email          login_date
001       a@gmail.com    2015-11-18 22:02:41.153
001       a@gmail.com    xxx
```

I have another table called userLoged where I have the columns `usercode`, `email` and `web_access`

UserLoged table:

```
usercode email         web_access
001      a@gmail.com   Y
```

Now, if a@gmail.com (001) is not logged in for 45 days, i need to update web_access to be 'N'

How to know if he /she not logged for 45 days?

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking but to find rows that haven't logged in you can simple use some date math. Where LastLoginID < DATEADD(DAY, -45, GETDATE())

Answer (score 2):

I think a better thing for you to do, rather than storing a static 'Y' or 'N', is to query the last logged in date each time you need it.

If you really need the 'Y' or 'N' field, you could try a calculated field or have a SQL Job to run every day that runs [Aaron D's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33835916/403404) query.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT USERCODE
FROM LOGIN
INTO @TEMP
WHERE MAX(login_date) <= CONVERT(date(getdate()-45,101)

UPDATE USERLOGED
SET web_access = 'N'
WHERE USERCODE in (
    SELECT USERCODE
    FROM @TEMP)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
create table userLog(
usercode nvarchar(50) null,
email varchar(50),
login_date datetime
)

create table UserLoged(
usercode nvarchar(50),
web_access char
)
insert into UserLoged values
('001', 'Y'),
('002', 'Y')

insert into userLog values
('001', 'user@gmail.com', '2015-09-18 21:02:41.153'),
('001', 'user@gmail.com', '2015-09-18 22:02:41.153'),
('002', 'user@gmail.com', '2015-11-18 22:02:41.153')

update a
    set web_access = 'N'
from UserLoged a
    join userLog b
    on a.usercode = b.usercode
where DATEDIFF(day, login_date, getdate()) >= 45

select * from UserLoged
```